# How to start WPF application using WinForms Application

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am trying to start a WPF application using WinForms application.

Here is my code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run(new MainWindow());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I click the button it will load WPF app. Then if I close the WPF and click the button again then I get the following error

Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initiate more than one instance in App class. so you can solve this out using one App instance.Answer is following

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        App app;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            app = new App();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                app.InitializeComponent();
                app.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                app.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
                app.MainWindow.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```